# Run a function with a given delay continuously

Tags: java, android

I need to run the below piece of code continuously with delay obtained by this

```
PropertyListClass.PropertyDelay.get(i)

 if(PropertyListClass.actionTodo.get(i)==SET)
            {
                setProperty(PropertyListClass.PropertyNumber.get(i),PropertyListClass.PropertyValue.get(i));
            }
            else if(PropertyListClass.actionTodo.get(i)==GET)
            {
                returnedVal = getProperty(PropertyListClass.PropertyNumber.get(i));
                if(returnedVal==PropertyListClass.PropertyValue.get(i))
                {
                    PassedTestCase.setText(passed+1);
                }
                else{
                    FailedTestCase.setText(failed+1);
                }
            }
```

This action i am triggering on the press of a button. Please suggest some way. This could be executed for hours together.

Comment: Can you elaborate more how exactly you want to implement delay?

Comment: PropertyListClass.PropertyDelay.get(i)

Comment: I ll be obtaining delay from the above code. The if and else if need to run continously after that delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given a partial code so I am not able to understand the whole scenario here, but Here's how you can add delay in android:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do task after the delay
        }
    }, 2000); // 2000 - delay time in mili seconds
```

The code inside `run()` will be executed after the delay, so according to your delay time, you can use this code to add delays.

Comment: How will i trigger this from a button?

Comment: I guess one way is If you are trying to run it continuously then use it inside a loop, and stop the loop when you want to stop. And if you want to run it when a button is pressed then keep it inside a button click listener.